# Facing issues with storing variable results in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have to store all the matching results in a file using postprocessor. Below is response body. i am able to extract all the matching results and storing it in file.

```
events":[
               {
                 "idWorkflow":3,
                 "idCase":3754,
                 "idWorkitem":4059,
                 "displayName":"Inform RPA to Register SOP in CRM",
                 "type":"activity",
                  "date":"05/21/2021 13:38",
                 "status":"closed",
                 "assignee":"f3044857-7233-449c-9abe-f44e48616c8e",
                 "containsMoreAssignees":false
                },
                {
                  "idWorkflow":21,
                  "idCase":3454,
                  "idWorkitem":3790,
                  "displayName":"Get & evaluate CDWH Data",
                  "type":"activity",
                  "date":"05/21/2021 13:38",
                  "status":"closed",
                  "assignee":"f3044857-7233-449c-9abe-f44e48616c8e",
                  "containsMoreAssignees":false
                   }`
```

Here in above response body, i need to extract all "displayName" & "date" field values with correct order.
Expected results : "Inform RPA to Register SOP in CRM" - 05/21/2021 13:38
"Get & evaluate CDWH data" - 05/21/2021 13:38"
Below is my code

```
  import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
                 import java.io.FileOutputStream;
                 import java.util.Map;
                 import java.util.Set;
                  def resultCount = vars.get("c_date_matchNr")
                  def activity = vars.get("c_displayName_matchNr")
                    for (int i = 1; i <= resultCount.toInteger(); i++) {
                        records = vars.get("c_date_" + i)
                        for (int j = 1; j <= activity.toInteger(); j++) {
                            list = vars.get("c_displayName_" + j)

                            FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("C:/final.csv", true);
                            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
                            out.write(records);
                            out.write("-");
                            out.write(list);
                            out.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                            out.close();
                            fstream.close();
                        }

                    }
```

Above code storing the results but same line printed multiple times. Could someone please explain what is issue in this code or is there any other alternate way to do the same in JMeter

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at values of the `c_displayName` and `c_date` variable variables using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script), it might be the case the variables have duplicate values.

The alternative way would be [parsing the response completely in Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html) without using any other Post-Processors:

```
new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).events.each { event ->
    new File('c:/final.csv') << event.get('displayName') << '-' << event.get('date') << System.getProperty('line.separator')
}
```

If you run your test with more than one user/iteration you will see more than one occurrence of the "activities", moreover the data might be corrupted due to the [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) so it might be a better idea to consider using i.e. [Flexible File Writer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/)

Comment: Sure Dmitri. I will consider Flexible file writer option. Is there a way to store only variable response(ex: "c_display name") in a file using Flexible file writer option.